# SQL use select statement to add build a table - no insert op

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, geospatial

I need to use the select statement to form a table

```
DECLARE @MetresPerMile FLOAT = 1609.344;
DECLARE @LOCStart1 GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(48.83000,-97.31000,4326)
DECLARE @LOCDest1 GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(48.83000,-97.31000,4326)
DECLARE @LOCStart2 GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(22.9230000,-94.5342000,4326)
DECLARE @LOCDest2 GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(22.9230000,-94.5342000,4326)

SELECT 
    '1' [Start], '1' [Dest], 
    @LOCStart1.STDistance(@LOCDest1) / @MetresPerMile [Distance],
    '2' [Start], '2' [Dest],
    @LOCStart2.STDistance(@LOCDest1) / @MetresPerMile [Distance];
```

The result I'm getting is 6 columns, I just need 3 columns:

[image]

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and produce a [mre]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With kudos to Marc Guillot for his answer, does this get your desired result?

```sql
declare @MetresPerMile float = 1609.344;

with Points as (
  select *
  from (values
    (1, GEOGRAPHY::Point(48.83000,-97.31000,4326)),
    (2, GEOGRAPHY::Point(22.9230000,-94.5342000,4326))
  ) pts (Id, Point)
)
select Start.Id as Start, Dest.Id as Dest, 
       Start.Point.STDistance(Dest.Point)/@MetresPerMile as Distance
from Points as Start
cross join Points as Dest
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you that result :

```
declare @MetresPerMile float = 1609.344;
declare @Points table (Id integer, Point geography);

insert into @Points (Id, Point) 
       values (1, GEOGRAPHY::Point(48.83000,-97.31000,4326)),
              (2, GEOGRAPHY::Point(22.9230000,-94.5342000,4326));

select Start.Id as Start, Dest.Id as Dest, 
       Start.Point.STDistance(Dest.Point)/@MetresPerMile
from @Points as Start
     cross join @Points as Dest
```

You can add as many point as you need in the Points table, and the select will return the distances between all of them.

You can see it working here : [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a45bf2cd198c8dd57eb35a88cd11f44c)

Comment: I'm getting an error on the last line. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'End'.

Comment: Does that actually work for you? After replacing `End` with `Dest` on SQL 2019 I get... _The data type geography cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable._

Comment: With Points as Dest - The data type geography cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable.

Comment: @suhabari No, I don't have any SQL Server at hand at this moment to try it, so I'm writting it from memory. If geography fields cannot be unioned, will it work for you with a table variable ?. I have updated my proposal.